# How to get values in expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, delegates

I am having expression   `s => s.Application.Id`

I want to get Application.Id.

As expression can be vary in next case to

```
s=s.Application.ApplicationType.Id
```

in this case i want `Application.ApplicationType.Id`

I had try with expression.body.member.name

It gives me Id.

Comment: You can compile that expression and execute it passing `s` object to it.

Comment: Any other way to do. I don't want to compile and execute it.

Comment: there are two ways you get it be iterating all properties in the list using reflection, or compile it and execute as `Func<>`

Comment: can you tell me how to do with reflection. you can consider var sourc is variable having expression s=s.Application.Id.

Comment: I'll update my answer with reflection in a second

Comment: @Sergey i don't want the value. Your example gives me 42 as answer. As expected answer is Application.Id not the value of Application.Id

Comment: You just want to get text representation?

Comment: Yes i just want test expression which remove s=>s part and gives remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to compile or anything fancy. Just walk the expression tree recursively to assemble the full path.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = GetPropertyName<Test>(x => x.Test2.Application.Id);
    }

    static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return GetMemberExpressionPath(memberExpression);
    }

    static string GetMemberExpressionPath(MemberExpression exp)
    {
        string s = null;

        var rootExp = exp.Expression as MemberExpression;
        if (rootExp != null)
        {
            s = GetMemberExpressionPath(rootExp);
        }

        //var paramExp = exp.Expression as ParameterExpression;
        //if (paramExp != null)
        //{
        //    s = paramExp.Name;
        //}

        return (s != null ? s + "." : "") + exp.Member.Name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it with ExpressionVisitor that just remembers parameter expression and cuts it from the begginging like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<Parent, int>> expression = s => s.Application.ID;

        var val = new CustomVisitor().ConvertToString(expression);

        Console.WriteLine("expression is " + val);
    }
}

public class CustomVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression _param;

    private Expression _body;

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        _body = node.Body;
        return base.VisitLambda(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        _param = node;
        return node;
    }

    public string ConvertToString(Expression expression)
    {
        Visit(expression);

        var parameterLength = _param.Name.Length + 1; // cuts name plus dot
        return _body.ToString().Substring(parameterLength);
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public Application Application {get;set;}
}

public class Application
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

Here is working sample on DotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fmye6z